In my solution I have an isolated ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project with identity. I want to add a MVC project to use the existing identity
In my solution, I have a separate ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project with identity.
Now I want add another ASP.NET Core MVC project to the solution, that uses the existing identity infrastructure.
Solution structure:
MySolution:

IdentityWebAPIProject
AnotherMCVProject

This project use the above Identity WebAPI endpoints for the usual tasks, Login, Register, Forgotpassword, etc.
I would like to Scafflod identity pages, BUT, that use the IdentityWebAPIProject endpoints, not a local DbContext



Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

I would like to Scafflod identity pages, BUT, that use the IdentityWebAPIProject endpoints, not a local DbContext  ---as far as I known,it's not supported now

You can call IdentityWebAPIProject from AnotherMCVProject via HTTP calls and HttpClient.
UPD.
Additional option will be to refactor the solution to move out shared code to a separate library. Then you will be able to reuse the code and to use a single database for 2 projects.

Hi. Yes I believe that I can do it. But Is it possible to create a MVC project from a Template that implement all identity functionality as We can create when We create a new project and indicate individual accounts?

I'm just interested why you would want to do that. My original answer adds complexity that you don't want to handle. In addition, you can generate identity code from the template, but you will want to write custom code to use a single database in 2 projects.
